# java random number generator separate classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for help creating a random number generator that simulates a lottery. 
Write code for the method that generates 5 random mega numbers out of the given
range of numbers. Two of them must be even numbers, and the remaining three
numbers must be odd numbers. Use the modulus operator (%) to check if a number is
even or odd. Note that no duplicate numbers are allowed and numbers should range between 1 and 50.
In a separate class I need to create a MegaBall number that when launched another random number between 1-30 is generated.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!

```
public class MegaBall {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        int[] lottoNumber = new int[5];
    {`public class MegaBall {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        int[] lottoNumber = new int[5];
    {
    lottoNumber[0] = (int) ((50 * Math.random()) + 1);
    lottoNumber[1] = (int) ((50 * Math.random()) + 1);
    lottoNumber[2] = (int) ((50 * Math.random()) + 1);
    lottoNumber[3] = (int) ((50 * Math.random()) + 1);
    lottoNumber[4] = (int) ((50 * Math.random()) + 1);
    }

    System.out.print("Lottery Numbers: ");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

how do I get the 2 even and 3 odd numbers that are not the same?

Comment: What part of this _specifically_ do you need help with?  What is not working, or don't you understand?

Comment: This is not a 'here is my assignment, thanks!' site; we answer questions in the form of 'here is my MCVE, here is the error, here is what I have tried, how can I fix it?'.

Comment: We're sorry, the `code writing service` is currently down.  Please try again later.

Comment: `Write code for the method...` it sounds very much like you've just copy & pasted your homework here. Not that homework questions aren't allowed, but you need to show your own effort so far and ask a much more specific question.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Replace "full code" with "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and your statement is accurate.

Comment: Do not put code in comments. Edit your original post and format it there so it's actually readable. Please also explain the specific problem with your code. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and read this *carefully*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BigTom Please take a second look at the link I posted about formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting EDIT your ORIGINAL POST. ("edit" button immediately beneath the `java` and `eclipse` tags) Not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take this, it works:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by cullycross on 2/6/15.
 */
public class Lottery {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        LittleLottery lottery = new LittleLottery();

        lottery.showNums(lottery.getRandomNumbers());
        lottery.showNums(lottery.getRandomNum());

    }

    static class LittleLottery {

        private final int COUNT_OF_NUMS = 5;
        private final int MAX_RANDOM = 50;
        private final int MAXI_BALL = 30;
        private final Random mRandom = new Random();

        public Integer [] getRandomNumbers() {

            HashSet<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>(COUNT_OF_NUMS);

            for(int i = 0; i < COUNT_OF_NUMS; i++) {

                Integer temp;
                while (true){
                    temp = mRandom.nextInt(MAX_RANDOM) + 1;
                    if ((i + 1) % 2 == temp % 2
                            && nums.add(temp)) {

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return nums.toArray(new Integer[COUNT_OF_NUMS]);
        }

        public Integer getRandomNum() {
            return mRandom.nextInt(MAXI_BALL) + 1;
        }

        public void showNums(Integer... args) {
            for(Integer i : args) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```